# SQL Optimize way to query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Query `INNER JOIN` with `SUB Query`. I use `Aggregate Function(MIN & MAX)` and `Group By`. In my Sub Query, I calculate the Date & Time Differences and I name it `TotalTime` Column. My problem is, when 2 or more record are retrieved it will calculate the whole date_request within the Date Range I input.(*Please see my sample query code  below*)

here's my query:

```
SELECT tblOT_Details.userid,(tblUsers.firstname + ' ' +tblUsers.lastname) AS name,
tblOT_Details.task,tblOT_Details.date_request,
MIN(tblOT_Details.time_from) AS time_from,MAX(tblOT_Details.time_to) AS time_to,
totaltime = (select datediff(HOUR,0,ET-ST) + cast(datediff(MI,0,ET-ST) - (datediff(HOUR,0,ET-ST) * 60) As Decimal) / 100 
           from
           (
            select
                ST=convert(datetime,MIN(tblOT_Details.time_from)),
                ET=convert(datetime,MAX(tblOT_Details.time_to)) from tblOT_Details
                  WHERE userid IN ('USER1','USER2','USER3')
                  AND date_request BETWEEN '09/01/2014' AND '10/25/2014' ---> I know here is the problem. Should I use Looping Here to get the specific totalhours per user? 
            ) a 
        ),
tblOT.Approved_by
FROM tblOT_Details
INNER JOIN tblOT
ON tblOT_Details.userid = tblOT.requested_by
AND CONVERT(varchar,tblOT_Details.date_request,101) = CONVERT(varchar,tblOT.date_request,101)
INNER JOIN tblUsers
ON tblOT_Details.userid = tblUsers.User_Id
WHERE tblOT_Details.userid IN ('USER1','USER2','USER3')
AND tblOT.status='Approved'
AND tblOT_Details.totaltime IS NOT NULL
AND tblOT_Details.date_request BETWEEN '09/01/2014' AND '10/25/2014'
GROUP BY tblOT_Details.userid,(tblUsers.firstname + ' ' +tblUsers.lastname),tblOT_Details.task,tblOT_Details.date_request,tblOT.Approved_by
ORDER BY tblOT_Details.date_request ASC
```

Here's my Sample Query Table:

[image]

[PROOF THAT IT CALCULATES THROUGHOUT DATE RANGE](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=15&m1=9&y1=2014&d2=21&m2=10&y2=2014&h1=18&i1=02&s1=36&h2=22&i2=19&s2=11)

As you can see in Column Name `TotalTime` it's all the same numbers because it calculates the date range I input in `BETWEEN` the function. And my question is, should I use loop in every date range just to get the specific `min&max date` per user? or do you have some optimize/better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the subquery and your query is like

```
select col1,col2,'aaa' from tablename
```

This will work for each user

```
SELECT tblOT_Details.userid,
       ( tblUsers.firstname + ' ' + tblUsers.lastname )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           AS NAME,
       tblOT_Details.task,
       tblOT_Details.date_request,
       Min(tblOT_Details.time_from)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               AS time_from,
       Max(tblOT_Details.time_to)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 AS time_to,
       Datediff(HOUR, 0, CONVERT(DATETIME, Max(tblOT_Details.time_to)) - CONVERT(DATETIME, Min(tblOT_Details.time_from))) + Cast(Datediff(MI, 0, CONVERT(DATETIME, Max(tblOT_Details.time_to)) - CONVERT(DATETIME, Min(tblOT_Details.time_from))) - ( Datediff(HOUR, 0, CONVERT(DATETIME, Max(tblOT_Details.time_to)) - CONVERT(DATETIME, Min(tblOT_Details.time_from))) * 60 ) AS DECIMAL) / 100 tblOT.Approved_by
FROM   tblOT_Details
       INNER JOIN tblOT
               ON tblOT_Details.userid = tblOT.requested_by
                  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, tblOT_Details.date_request, 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, tblOT.date_request, 101)
       INNER JOIN tblUsers
               ON tblOT_Details.userid = tblUsers.User_Id
WHERE  tblOT_Details.userid IN ( 'USER1', 'USER2', 'USER3' )
       AND tblOT.status = 'Approved'
       AND tblOT_Details.totaltime IS NOT NULL
       AND tblOT_Details.date_request BETWEEN '09/01/2014' AND '10/25/2014'
GROUP  BY tblOT_Details.userid,
          ( tblUsers.firstname + ' ' + tblUsers.lastname ),
          tblOT_Details.task,
          tblOT_Details.date_request,
          tblOT.Approved_by
ORDER  BY tblOT_Details.date_request ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn CTE:

```
;WITH cte_ot AS (
SELECT UserID, date_request, SUM(     DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, time_to - time_from) + CAST(DATEDIFF(MI, 0, time_to - time_from) - DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, time_to - time_from) * 60 AS Decimal) / 100) as TotalTime
FROM         tblOT_Details
GROUP BY UserID, date_request
)

select UserID, date_request, TotalTime
from cte
--add join here
```